# How to check if an element exists in an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

```
NSInteger indexOfMatchedObject = [self.array indexOfObject:object.objectId];
```

i need to check if there is value in `indexOfMatchedObject` or not, how can i do this?

Comment: Check for NSNotFound, look at the doc. of `indexOfObject:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the constant `NSNotFound` to determine whether the object was present in the array or not.

Comment: so i just do `if (indexOfMatchedObject == NSNotFound)` ?

Comment: how would i check if there is a value?

Comment: @farhan if it's not `NSNotFound` then it'll contain the found object's index in the array. It'll always have a value.

Comment: for some reason even though it should have nothing in the array it says it does.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to check the array contains the value or not **[self.array containsObject:object.objectId]**. This will return bool value.